# How to have a config.js file as an external (it being required during run time and not bundled) in webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am new to webpack. I am making a react application which will read text from an external config.js file and display it on the UI. I am trying to have a external config.js file which I dont want to be bundled but be required during run time. 
This is my webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const html_plugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './src/app.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname,'build'),
        filename: 'build.js'
    },
    externals: {
        config: './config.js',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: 'babel-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader','css-loader']
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [new html_plugin({ template: './src/index.html' })]
}
```

The config.js is in the same directory as webpack.config.js. 
This is my config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    title: 'ssup'
}
```

This is how I am using my config.js in a component:

```
import config from 'config';
 class ... {
      return <h1>{config.title}</h1>
 }
```

Here is my project structure:

```
- src/
- webpack.config.js
- config.js
```

When I try to run this application, it shows the following error in my chrome console:
[image]

the line 681 in build.js contains this:

```
eval("module.exports = ./config.js;\n\n//# sourceURL=webpack:///external_%22./config.js%22?");
```

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "react-from-scratch",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.10.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.6.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.6.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "css-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "webpack": "^4.41.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.9",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.8.2"
  }
}
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any webpack configuration to do that. Save your config as JSON and `fetch` it at runtime instead of build time.

Also, what are you trying to achieve using this technique? What is your use case?

Comment: I am developing an SPA, which my clients can customize its behavior using an external config.js. eg: they can set the date format displayed on a calendar, or if they want to show a calendar or something else on a page, or change title of a page etc.

Below is an example file:
`{
     calendarStartTime: 9:00,
     calendarEndTime: 19:00,
     homeScreenTitle: 'Welcome',
}`. Changing any of these values and refreshing the page will reflect these changes in the application.

Comment: If you still recommend using `fetch`, can you give me an example code of how can I do that.

Comment: Ok, so `fetch` is definitely the way to go. You'll need to do 3 things:

(1) `JSON.stringify(yourConfigObject)` and save that to a `.json` file then upload it to your web server/CDN. (2) Use `window.fetch` to get that file in your app at runtime. (3) Make sure the details work out. Specifically CORS and the async nature of `fetch`. There's countless examples and tutorials online for those two.

Comment: But I don't want to have the file on a server or a cdn. I want to have it locally as `config.js` in the build folder. The `build.js` file should read from it during run time. Our previous apps were built using requireJs and they worked this way. The build file would read from the config.js every time we refresh the page. Is there anyway to replicate this with webpack?

Comment: First, if your config only contains data then it shouldn't be JS. It should be JSON. If your "config" has functions, classes and runs code then it isn't config - it is code and that's different. You can still load it though - just not using `fetch`. As for your question (regardless of whether it is JS or JSON): put it in `/build` after building and you're done.

Comment: My `config.js` returns a `json object` with values as strings. It does not have any functions or runs code. If I put it in build folder, how will the build.js know to require that file at run time. That is the issue I am facing. If you look at my question, I added the `config.js` as an external in my `webpack.config`. But when I do `npm start`, it throws the error. I tried making a build with `npm run build` and moved my `config.js` into the build folder, and it throws the same error. Is there any issue in my `webpack.config`?

Comment: If your config only has values then it should be `.json`, regardless of how you load/import/fetch it. Now, what you need to do is to `const config = await import('./path/to/your/config.json')` in your app, regardless of where you host it. There are countless examples of that online and you don't need any webpack configuration for it.